# jquery ajax returns status code 0 while requesting cross domain

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

i am trying to make cross domain request but server can not response with

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

i am trying to read response header.
when i am trying to read status code or ready state it returns 0. my code for ajax request is as follows.

```
$.ajax({
       url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
       type: "POST",
        data:   {"response_type":"token","client_id":"6720XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:51967/oauth2callback.aspx","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar","state":"this is state information","approval_prompt":"auto"},            
                crossDomain: true
        }).always(function(jqxhr,testStatus,errorThrown)
        {
                alert(jqxhr.readyState);
                alert(jqxhr.status);
        });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

have you try [this jquery crossdomain](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/) plugin?

another way is using `jsonp` as response type

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   ...
```

Comment: then the server will return 400 error because it accept only certain data as post when using jsonp it send other data such as callback=jQuery19009566406458362526_13611668XXX